# large PAGE size for XFS block size

Tags: filesystems, ubuntu-14.04, xfs

I am using  ubuntu 14 LTS x86_64 with Page size 4096 (bytes). XFS documentation suggests that  block size of XFS can not exceed kernel PAGE Size. Do I need to use huge Pages to increase File system block size

Could you also suggest if there are alternative possible as I could not find any

Answer (score 1):

XFS, like every most other Linux filesystems, is limited to a maximum of PAGE_SIZE filesystem block size.  On x86_64, you will be limited to 4k.
You can mkfs.xfs a larger block size, but you will not be able to mount it if the block size is larger than PAGE_SIZE.